# Python package - No module found when installing without -e option, works with -e option

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging

I've been trying to build a testing python package, but I came across this issue.

When I `pip install -e project-name` the package to virtual environment, everything works as its supposed to, but when I try to install it without the editable option and run it, it throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PATH/my-venv/bin/project-name", line 7, in <module>
    from main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

Here is my setup.cfg entry-point :

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts = 
    project-name=main:main
```

and project tree:

```
.
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── projectName.py
```

If any more info is needed, I can send more.

Anyone knows what to do? Thank a lot.

Comment: The directory structure of the project does not correctly follow the `src`-layout. In the `src` directory there should be the directory corresponding to the top-level import package of your project. For example instead of `src/__init__.py`, there should be `src/package_name/__init__.py`. I recommend you check this [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and the [*setuptools* doc](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout), pay close attention to the directory structure.

Comment: @sinoroc thanks, reworked the dir tree and works properly.

Comment: Good. I recommend you answer your own question with the corrected project directory structure.